# Groups acting on set.

Tags: abstract-algebra

How does the group, G,  of order 4 act on a set, S,  of order 6?

So i understand that this group action is the same as a group homomorphism 
T:G--> Aut(S). So it sends Z/4 to S6, where S6 is the symmetric group on 6 elements. I am confused as to how to proceed from here. Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You say "the group, $G$, of order $4$", without having said _which_ group of order $4$.  There are two of them. $\qquad$

Comment: Sorry z/4 is the group of order 4 which I am working with

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but might send you in the right direction.

$1\in\mathbb Z_4$ generates $\mathbb Z_4$ so a grouphomomorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z_4\to S_6$ is completely determined by $\phi(1)$.

Secondly $1\in\mathbb Z_4$ has order $4$. So $\phi(1)\in S_6$ must have an order that divides $4$.

Go searching for elements in $S_6$ that have order $1,2$ or $4$.

Comment: Why is Z/4 not generated by 2 or 3?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_4=\{0,1,2,3\}$ equipped with addition modulo $4$. It is generated by all elements that have order $4$ wich are $1$ and $3$. Not by $2$ since $2+2=0$ mod $4$ so it has order $2$.

Comment: Go it. So how come I can't say that the group homomorphism is not determined by pi(3)?

Comment: Who told you that you can't say that? Not me. Yes, you can also say that it is determined by $\phi(3)$.

Comment: Above it says that the group homomorphism "is completely determined by pi(1)."

Comment: Not completely in the sense that other elements cannot determine it. But in the following sense: if you know the value of $\phi(1)$ then you know all values $\phi(0),\phi(1),\phi(2),\phi(3)$. The same is true for $\phi(3)$.